# I can't make it compile and the types match

Tags: haskell

In my servant app I have this:

```
getItems :: Maybe String -> ExceptT ServantErr IO [MyData]
getItems myHdr = 
  case myHdr of
    Nothing -> throwE err403
    Just myHdrVal -> do
      case myHdrVal of
        "aaabbbcc" -> liftIO $ do
          print "gooood!"
          query_ cn "select * from table1"

        _ -> throwE err403 -- I want to add "print"
```

This works fine. However, the following doesn't compile due to the types mismatch:

```
  _ -> print "not gooood" >> throwE err403

  -- or
  _ -> liftIO $ do 
    print "not gooood"
    throwE err403

  -- or
  _ -> liftIO =<< (print "not gooood" >> throwE err403) -- incorrect, though
```

How to fix it?

Comment: well I cannot try it right now but what about doing `_ -> do` and then `liftIO (print "not good")` and then `throwE err403` (all on new lines the last two indented to the same level - you get what I mean I hope) - see: `throwE` is obviously a function returning the right type - you don't have to lift it

Comment: @Carsten that's the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well based on my comment and the encouragement from haoformayor this should do the trick:

```
  _ -> do 
    liftIO $ print "not gooood"
    throwE err403
```

notice that you only have to lift the `print` as this one is "works" in the `IO` monad but not the `throwE` as it obviously return the right type already

of course

```
_ -> liftIO (print "not gooood") >> throwE err403
```

should work too if you like

---

#### disclaimer

I did not test this